# Как оптимизировать подсчет вариантов прохождения маршрута?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, стек, динамический-анализ

Есть функция, которая считает кол-во вариантов прохождения маршрута, если игрок за раз может пройти не более чем n точек. Маршрут - линейный, представляет из себя прямую от 1..k, соответсвенно, игрок за раз не может пройти более n делений данной шкалы. Например, до точки 3, если игрок за раз может "перепрыгивать" 3 точки, будет содержать 7 вариантов, и т.д. Вообще, в линейном программирование задача известна как задача о кузнечике. Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в алгоритмах, но задачу в принципе решил, за исключением оптимизации. Для входа 300х300 поиск кол-ва ходов занимает 1 минуту 45 секунд. Может у вас будут советы по оптимизации?

```
#include <deque>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LongNumber {
private: deque<int> longViewParam;

public: LongNumber() {

}
public: ~LongNumber() {
    longViewParam.~deque();
}
public:void parse(long long arg) {
    while (arg > 0) {
        longViewParam.push_front(arg % 10);
        arg = arg / 10;
    }

}
public: void representation(stack<int> representValue) {
    longViewParam.clear();
    while (representValue.size() > 0) {
        longViewParam.push_back(representValue.top());
        representValue.pop();
    }
}

public: stack<int> SumLongNumber(deque<int> da, deque<int> db) {
    stack<int> result;
    if (da.size() >= db.size()) {
        int shiftFlag = 0;
        while (da.size() > 0) {
            if (db.size() > 0) {
                int operationBuffer = da.back() + db.back() + shiftFlag;
                if ((operationBuffer / 10) > 0) {
                    shiftFlag = operationBuffer / 10;
                    result.push(operationBuffer % 10);
                }
                else {
                    result.push(operationBuffer);
                    shiftFlag = 0;
                }
                db.pop_back();
            }
            else {
                result.push(da.back() + shiftFlag);
                shiftFlag = 0;
            }
            da.pop_back();
        }
        if (shiftFlag > 0) {
            result.push(shiftFlag);
            shiftFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        int shiftFlag = 0;
        while (db.size() > 0) {
            if (da.size() > 0) {
                int operationBuffer = da.back() + db.back() + shiftFlag;
                if ((operationBuffer / 10) > 0) {
                    shiftFlag = operationBuffer / 10;
                    result.push(operationBuffer % 10);
                }
                else {
                    result.push(operationBuffer);
                    shiftFlag = 0;
                }
                da.pop_back();
            }
            else {
                result.push(db.back() + shiftFlag);
                shiftFlag = 0;
            }
            db.pop_back();
        }
        if (shiftFlag > 0) {
            result.push(shiftFlag);
            shiftFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public:void Print() {
    deque<int> tempParam = longViewParam;
    while (tempParam.size() > 0) {
        cout << tempParam.front();
        tempParam.pop_front();
    }
}
public: deque<int> GetValue() {
    return longViewParam;
}

public: LongNumber operator+ (LongNumber arg) {
    LongNumber tempObject;
    tempObject.representation(tempObject.SumLongNumber(arg.longViewParam, this->longViewParam));
    return tempObject;
}
};
LongNumber Jumper(int posCounter, int sizeBlock) {
    LongNumber tempObject;
    tempObject.parse(1);
    LongNumber *buffer;
    if (sizeBlock >= 1) {
        buffer = new LongNumber[sizeBlock + 1];
        int counter = 0;
        buffer[0].parse(1);
        buffer[1].parse(1);

        for (int i = 2; i < sizeBlock + 1; ++i) {
            buffer[i].parse(0);
        }
        if (posCounter == 0 || posCounter == 1) {
            return tempObject;
        }
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeBlock + 1; ++i) {
                LongNumber temp;
                temp.parse(0);
                for (int j = 0; j < sizeBlock + 1; ++j) {
                    if (j != i) {
                        temp = temp + buffer[j];
                    }
                }
                buffer[i] = temp;
                if (counter == posCounter) {
                    return temp;
                }
                ++counter;
            }
        }
    }
    return tempObject;
}
int main() {
    Jumper(300, 300).Print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Опечатался, 4 точки за раз.

Comment: Забавно - ваша программа у меня работала меньше секунды, выдала 10185179881672430431342228442046890805257341968329681253180702246771906498816683‌​53091698688... Не думаю, что у вас машина медленнее на два порядка :) Компилировал Visual C++ 2015. И еще - если я верно понял, при беглом взгляде, то вы держите по одной _десятичной_ цифре в `int`. Не расточительно ли? Там же можно держать если и не весь `int`, то хотя бы 2 байта - чтоб даже при умножении переполнений не было. И памяти перерасход, и времени...

Comment: longViewParam.~deque(); - дурацкий явный вызов деструктора у не динамического объекта. Кто вас такой глупости научил? Выбросьте, это - ошибка.

Comment: @dr.Zilderman , если опечатались, то внесите изменение в текст вопроса, а свой комментарий об опечатке удалите.

Comment: А вы включили оптимизацию при выполнении? Это флаг O2 либо O3 у копмилятора

Comment: И плюсану по поводу базы - 10 слишком медленно, используйте `0х10000=65536`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько технических советов:

- передавайте сложные объекты по ссылке (например, `SumLongNumber(deque<int>& da, deque<int>& db)`), так как это гораздо быстрее (сейчас всё без раздумий передаётся по значению, что должно ощутимо тормозить процесс),
- `operator+` можно было бы сделать более быстрым, если избавиться от создания промежуточного объекта (в этом же как раз состоит смысл этого оператора),
- деление на 10 - это медленная операция. Лучше хранить длинные целые числа в структурах с хорошим основанием (степенью двойки), а в десятичный вид переводить в последний момент (для вывода на экран),
- и не используйте `system("pause");`, так как это добавляет зависимость от ОС и вообще опасно (мало ли что в той системе делается при вызове "pause").